# Node Javascript - string variable setting to literal instead of its' value

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database

I'm playing around with a Node server and having trouble setting values in Firebase with a provided String.

**The issue:** When I try to set the value of the `carId` variable in the first line of the for loop, it is set as `carId: true` rather than the expected behavior --> `exampleCardId12345: true`.

Why is the value being set to `carId` rather than the value of the `carId` variable, which I set prior to the for loop?

```
 db.ref('/cars').once("value", function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
           var carId = data.key;
           var drivers = data.val().drivers;
           for(key in drivers) {
               db.ref('/carsById/'+key).set({carId: true});
           }
       });
 });
```

Comment: Read the question twice, can't tell what the problem is. I suggest you try again with actual code showing expected vs actual behaviour. Add some logging and explain what is not happening as expected

Comment: I'm confused.  You're creating a variable `carId` and setting the value to `data.key`.  You're then iterating over a collection of drivers, logging that same value every time.  Then doing nothing else with it.  What exactly are you expecting to have happen?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys, it is tricky. I am actually using the `carId` variable again to set it as the key in `db.ref('/carsById/'+key).set({carId: true});`. However, it is not setting the value of `carId` as the key but rather `carId` as the key. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use a variable's value for a key, use the [computed property name syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
db.ref('/carsById/'+key).set({ [carId]: true });
                               ^     ^
                               ^     ^
```